# Why is .pop() returning the whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to make a blackjack function.
For some reason, when I call .pop() on an array, it returns the whole array, where it is supposed to return just the last element.
The correct thing happens when I call it another time.

```
    var statsArr = blackjackStats[index];
    var cardsLeft = statsArr[0];
    var card1 = cardsLeft.pop();
    message.channel.send(card1);
    statsArr[1].push(card1);
```

```
    blackjackList.push(message.author.id);
    var curCards = arrShuffle(bjCards);
    var card1 = curCards.pop();
    var card2 = curCards.pop();
    var dCard1 = curCards.pop();
    var dCard2 = curCards.pop();
    var statsArr = [[curCards], [card1, card2], [dCard1, dCard2]];
    blackjackStats.push(statsArr);
```

The 2nd instance is where it is working, and the first instance is where it is not.

---

---

**NOT OP EDIT** : Lookalike snippet

```js
const blackjackStats = [
  [
    [
       'As',
       'King',
       'Queen',
    ],
  ],
];

const index = 0;

const statsArr = blackjackStats[index];
const cardsLeft = statsArr[0];
const card1 = cardsLeft.pop();

console.log(card1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: How did you see that `.pop()` was returning the whole array ? `.pop` does returns only one element of the array. My guess is that `cardsLeft` doesn't contains what you think. you should display it's content